# i am trying to make a get request but i keep getting this issue

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

```
    void getData() async {
    try {
      final response = await get(
        Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"),
      );
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
    } catch (err) {
      print('page failed to load');
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

> ```
>     /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.3/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:32:
> ```
>
> Error: Expected ')' before this.
> var ioRequest = (Coawait _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
> ^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.3/lib/src/io_client.dart:30:24:
> Error: The getter 'Coawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.
>
> ```
>  - 'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.3/lib/src/io_client.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Coawait'.
>       var ioRequest = (Coawait _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

1. flutter clean
2. delete http-0.13.3 packager from C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org
3. run pub get
   then try to run your app again